# How to get wireshark to sniff packets between client and server using VMs attached to NAT Network

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat, wireshark

I am really new to pen testing. I am using Oracle Virtualbox, and I have three kali linux VMs setup. I am trying to use wireshark on a VM to sniff packets between a Modbus client VM and a Modbus server VM where all three VMs are attached to the same NAT network.

All three are in promiscuous mode. I have tried port forwarding, but possibly my setup was incorrect, because I still was not able to see the packets.

I can see packets when I ping the wireshark VM from either of the other VMs, but I can not see any of the traffic from communication between the client VM and server VM.

I have the Modbus server listening on port 502 on the server VM, and the Modbus client VM is sending information to the server/port. I expect to see this traffic reflected in Wireshark. I am currently capturing all interfaces, but nothing appears.

I also have just tried pinging the client from the server and vice versa to see if that showed up in wireshark, but still nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I neglected to include some information that is needed to help, let me know.

Comment: @John NO. Please read question more carefully before you casually give suggestion. The sniffer is also one of the VMs. Your casual suggestion like this one could endanger someone's VM host and his/her home LAN.

Comment: @nendae I'm not sure which "NAT" mode you are talking about since there are at least two in VirtualBox, and one of them does not allow inter-VM communication. For your case you may consider Internal Networking (which AFAIK is basically a virtual bridge/switch that is isolated from the VM host): https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html (Btw, I'm not familiar with pentesting, but most likely you don't need to set up any port forwarding, rather you need to make sure the VMs are in one single broadcast domain.)

Comment: @John `if the main network is secure` you can literally put that after anything and makes it irrelevant. For example, "updating your system is unnecessary if it is secure". Besides, the host LAN is simply irrelevant to the context anyway, so even if you point was to "make things easier" (for Internet connectivity whatsoever), it doesn't make sense to casually suggest bridging as you did either, since you would make people think that bridging to the host LAN "is the key/solution". And I don't even want to bother discussing your "title says".

Comment: @John my point was never that the VMs shouldn't be in a same subnet, but that they don't need the host LAN to be in the same subnet. The OP can ultimately choose to bridge the VMs to the outside, but that doesn't mean that given the context it is necessary / the key.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. For further clarification this is for a class. I am using my computer at school, and so it is on their network. So, I wanted to keep everything between the VMs. I did try bridging, but couldn't get any of the VMs to connect to the network, and I think it has something to do with the campus IT requiring each computer to be registered before it is allowed to connect to the ethernet. So, I am back to NAT.

Comment: @Tom Yan thank you for the link. I was using the NAT service that allowed communication between the VMs. It says it is an internal network. However, I still can't seem to see communications between client VM and server VM when they are not communicating directly with the wireshark VM.

Comment: By `All three are in promiscuous mode`, did you mean that you actually set `Promiscuous Mode` to `Allow VM` (or `Allow All`) under the Network -> Adapter N -> Advanced in the VM Settings? (You only need to do that for the sniffing VM btw.)

Comment: Btw, while VirtualBox allows you to sniff on the third VM, it doesn't mean that it is the same case when it comes to actual switched Ethernet. *Its* so-called `Promiscuous Mode` actually refers to something like port monitoring / mirroring, apparently. You might want to read [this](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet#switched-ethernet) first if you actually want to *learn* pentesting.